# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\gcgon\.yarnrc'

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, windows-11

I'm having this problem when i try to initialize a new project using yarn or npm, this start happening in a day to another with no reason.

Every time i try to initiate a project this happens, they finished installation and delete all in sequence.

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX3KL.png)

Versions:

- yarn - 1.22.17
- npm - 7.6.3
- node - 15.12.0

obs: i'm using windows 11 :)

Answer (score 3):

That's because your .yarnrc file is hidden make sure you unhide then check.
it worked for me.

Unhide .yarnrc file

[image: 1]